# NSMutableURLRequest - Why will it not set header values with a regular NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

It appears that setting values for a header field (i.e. @"Content-Type") will not take the value unless it is base64 encoded. The method docs say it takes a plain NSString, so it really shouldn't matter. However, encoding it this way seems to render useless the value for the post request...right? 
See below:

```
[req setHTTPBody:allData];
     [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [req setValue:@"multipart/related; "
      "boundary==_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae\n" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 

     NSLog(@"\n\n\t\t===headerField content-type===\n\n%@", [req valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]);
```

Yields:

```
2010-12-22 09:53:23.008 uploadXMLText[96009:207] 

          ===headerField content-type===

(null)
```

But if I encode the value string @"multipart..." to base64:

Yields:

```
2010-12-22 10:06:37.185 uploadXMLText[96234:207] 

          ===headerField content-type===

bXVsdGlwYXJ0L3JlbGF0ZWQ7IGJvdW5kYXJ5PT1fMjdkYTYwZWUxM2I4NDc5`*
```

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Me

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the newline here: `boundary==_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae\n`. Change that to `boundary==_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae`. It is probably a way of protecting itself from you trying to inject additional headers.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, turns out you were right about the \n (newline) problem, but in more ways than you know. The NSMutableURLRequest won't add a header if it has a newline anywhere, which is why my Authorization header would never take (had a hidden \n at the end)!

Comment: Jonathan just formatted my post :) but one option is to percent encode so \n would become %0A but in the case of a multipart/related; header I am no expert so check out Endemic's answer see if that works in case %0A does not. NSString – stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:

Comment: Ya, thanks again. I just answered this thread at the bottom and it's working! I take it that %OA represents a newline?

Answer (score 0):

So first, thanks for all your answers!

Second, all the headers are in, the request is sending and I actually get a response from the server other than "400:your request sucks".

This:

```
NSMutableString *data = 
    @"--=_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae\n"
    "Content-Type: application/atom+xml\n\n"

    "<atom:entry xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">"
    "<media:group xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\">"
    "<media:category scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat\">Comedy</"
    "media:category><media:description>test</media:description><media:keywords>"
    "foo, var</media:keywords><media:title>test title</media:title></media:group></atom:entry>\n"
    "--=_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae\n"
    "Content-Type: video/mov\n"
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";



    NSMutableData *allData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [allData appendData:vidData];
    NSString *str = @"\n--=_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae--";
    [allData appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Sends this body:

```
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><media:group xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Comedy</media:category>
<media:description>test</media:description>
<media:keywords>foo, var</media:keywords><media:title>test title</media:title>
</media:group></atom:entry>
    --=_27da60ee13b84794c5873572c502aaae
    Content-Type: video/mov
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

It did end up working and uploaded the file!

So thanks once more for your help, and I hope this assists any future viewers.

MiL3s